# BIRT's page break doesn't work on IE 8

Tags: birt, page-break

We use BIRT report to generate HTML file, it works on IE 6, but it doesn't work on IE 8.

I download the HTML generated by BIRT and modify it to test. Finally, I found a solution to edit the HTML file directly.(see http://basdebie.com/problem-solvers/ie-8-page-break-afteralways-problem/).

But the problem is I cannot add the CSS in every page. I add it after body tag and it only shows in the 1st page. But table will shows in every page. Is there any solution to add it in every page in BIRT?

```
<body>
    <text id="896">
        <property name="contentType">auto</property>
        <text-property name="content"><![CDATA[ ]]></text-property>
    </text>
    <table id="16">
        <property name="width">100%</property>
        <property name="dataSet">Data Set</property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the a text element in page header and it works in IE 8 now.

```
        <page-header>
            <text id="897">
                <property name="contentType">auto</property>
                <text-property name="content"><![CDATA[ ]]></text-property>
            </text>
        </page-header>
```

BIRT generates the code in every pages.

```
        <div>
            <div id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_1" style=" text-align:left;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
```